# javascript function as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arguments

```
    // Compute factorials and cache results as properties of the function itself.
     function factorial(n) {
         if (isFinite(n) && n>0 && n==Math.round(n)) { // Finite, positive ints only
             if (!(n in factorial))                    // If no cached result
                 factorial[n] = n * factorial(n-1);    // Compute and cache it
             return factorial[n];                      // Return the cached result
         }
         else return NaN;                              // If input was bad
     }
     factorial[1] = 1; // Initialize the cache to hold this base case.
```

This code is from the book [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do)

I have following questions:

1)In the below line how is a function being used as an array?
`factorial[n] = n * factorial(n-1);  // Compute and cache`

2)How can we use `in` operator for a function argument like in the below line?
    `if (!(n in factorial))                    // If no cached`

**Edit:**

I got it that `factorial[1] = 1;` sets a property `'1':1` in the function factorial.

But is it possible to set a property of function as below?

```
function f() {
a: 2
}

alert(f.a);  //get 2 as output
```

Comment: in javascript functions are first class objects.... so they too have properties and methods

Comment: but the expression "parameter in function" always returns false

Comment: It is not used as an array, `factorial[1]` is just using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to access a property of `factorial` by the name of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

A function is still an object, so you can assign properties to that object. Basically you set 'n' as a property of factorial, so that you don't have to recalc it every time.
The 'in' operator functioning flows from this, by being roughly (but not completely) equivalent to factorial.hasOwnProperty(n) in this example.
So technically you're using the factorial function as a map with numbers as keys, which looks similar to an array.